# how to avoid multiple conditions in switch in a single object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

i getting one object sending from client side like this

```
var condition={"bedrooms":"1,2,3,4","Inhibition":"1,6","possession":"3","id":"8",toilets:"1,2",...,}
```

so it must be the same keys and only in single object but length may be 1/2/3/4/.. 
like this example:

```
    var condition={"bedrooms":"1,2,3,4","Inhibition":"1,6"};
    var condition={"bedrooms":"1,2,3,4"};
     var condition={"Inhibition":"1,6"};
    var condition={"id":"1,6"};
    var condition={"toilets":"1,6","possession":"3"};
var condition={"possession":"3"};
```

like this i have 10 keys 
so based on that i am getting almost 100 scenarios for different scenario i have to return the different object.so how can i handle all these scenarios by using switch and if else is not correct.

i tried like this

[image]
my code is :

```
 function comparison(condition,requestId,dbId){
        var obj={};
        var andCondition=[];
        var subCondition={};




 switch(true) {
        case (condition.hasOwnProperty("Inhibition") && !condition.hasOwnProperty("bedrooms") && !condition.hasOwnProperty("budgetPrice") && !condition.hasOwnProperty("possession")): {

            subCondition[dbId]=requestId;
            andCondition.push(subCondition,Sequelize.literal("`hp_property`.`hp_property_inhibition_status_id` IN (" + condition.Inhibition + ")"));

            obj['$and']=andCondition;

            return obj;

        };
        break;
        case (condition.hasOwnProperty("Inhibition") && condition.hasOwnProperty("bedrooms") && !condition.hasOwnProperty("budgetPrice") && !condition.hasOwnProperty("possession")): {
            subCondition[dbId]=requestId;
            andCondition.push(subCondition,Sequelize.literal("`hp_property`.`hp_property_inhibition_status_id` IN (" + condition.Inhibition + ")"),Sequelize.literal("`hp_unit_details`.`hp_unit_type_id` IN (" + condition.bedrooms + ")"));

            obj['$and']=andCondition;

            return obj;
        }
        break;

        case (condition.hasOwnProperty("Inhibition") && condition.hasOwnProperty("bedrooms") && condition.hasOwnProperty("budgetPrice") && !condition.hasOwnProperty("possession")): {
            var budgetPrice = condition.budgetPrice.split(",");
            var minRange = budgetPrice[0];
            var maxRange = budgetPrice[1];

            subCondition[dbId]=requestId;
            andCondition.push(subCondition,Sequelize.literal("`hp_property`.`hp_property_inhibition_status_id` IN (" + condition.Inhibition + ")"),Sequelize.literal("`hp_unit_details`.`hp_unit_type_id` IN (" + condition.bedrooms + ")"),Sequelize.literal("`hp_unit_details.hp_unit_prices`.`price_per_sqft` * `hp_unit_details`.`property_size`  BETWEEN " + minRange + " AND " + maxRange));

            obj['$and']=andCondition;

            return obj;
        }
            break;




        case (condition.hasOwnProperty("Inhibition") && condition.hasOwnProperty("bedrooms") && condition.hasOwnProperty("budgetPrice") && condition.hasOwnProperty("possession")): {
            var budgetPrice = condition.budgetPrice.split(",");
            var minRange = budgetPrice[0];
            var maxRange = budgetPrice[1];

            subCondition[dbId]=requestId;
            andCondition.push(subCondition,Sequelize.literal("`hp_property`.`hp_property_inhibition_status_id` IN (" + condition.Inhibition + ")"),Sequelize.literal("`hp_unit_details`.`hp_unit_type_id` IN (" + condition.bedrooms + ")"),Sequelize.literal("`hp_unit_details.hp_unit_prices`.`price_per_sqft` * `hp_unit_details`.`property_size`  BETWEEN " + minRange + " AND " + maxRange),Sequelize.literal("`hp_property`.`property_completion_date` between now() and DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL "+condition.possession+" MONTH)"));

            obj['$and']=andCondition;

            return obj;
        }
            break;



        case (condition.hasOwnProperty("bedrooms") && condition.hasOwnProperty("budgetPrice")): {
            var budgetPrice = condition.budgetPrice.split(",");
            var minRange = budgetPrice[0];
            var maxRange = budgetPrice[1];

            subCondition[dbId]=requestId;
            andCondition.push(subCondition,Sequelize.literal("`hp_unit_details`.`hp_unit_type_id` IN (" + condition.bedrooms + ")"),Sequelize.literal("`hp_unit_details.hp_unit_prices`.`price_per_sqft` * `hp_unit_details`.`property_size`  BETWEEN " + minRange + " AND " + maxRange));

            obj['$and']=andCondition;

            return obj;
        }
            break;


        case (condition.hasOwnProperty("bedrooms") && !condition.hasOwnProperty("budgetPrice") && !condition.hasOwnProperty("possession")): {

            subCondition[dbId]=requestId;
            andCondition.push(subCondition,Sequelize.literal("`hp_unit_details`.`hp_unit_type_id` IN (" + condition.bedrooms + ")"))
            obj['$and']=andCondition;

            return obj;
        }
            break;


        case (condition.hasOwnProperty("budgetPrice") && !condition.hasOwnProperty("bedrooms") && !condition.hasOwnProperty("possession")): {
            var budgetPrice = condition.budgetPrice.split(",");
            var minRange = budgetPrice[0];
            var maxRange = budgetPrice[1];

            subCondition[dbId]=requestId;
            andCondition.push(subCondition,Sequelize.literal("`hp_unit_details.hp_unit_prices`.`price_per_sqft` * `hp_unit_details`.`property_size`  BETWEEN " + minRange + " AND " + maxRange))
            obj['$and']=andCondition;

            return obj;
        }
            break;
        case (condition.hasOwnProperty("possession")  && !condition.hasOwnProperty("Inhibition") && !condition.hasOwnProperty("bedrooms") && !condition.hasOwnProperty("budgetPrice")): {
            subCondition[dbId]=requestId;
            andCondition.push(subCondition,Sequelize.literal("`hp_property`.`property_completion_date` between now() and DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL "+condition.possession+" MONTH)"))
            obj['$and']=andCondition;
            return obj;
        }

            break;

        case (condition.hasOwnProperty("possession") && condition.hasOwnProperty("bedrooms")  && !condition.hasOwnProperty("Inhibition") && !condition.hasOwnProperty("budgetPrice")): {

            subCondition[dbId]=requestId;
            andCondition.push(subCondition,Sequelize.literal("`hp_property`.`property_completion_date` between now() and DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL "+condition.possession+" MONTH)"),Sequelize.literal("`hp_unit_details`.`hp_unit_type_id` IN (" + condition.bedrooms + ")"))
            obj['$and']=andCondition;
            return obj;
        }
            break;

        case (condition.hasOwnProperty("possession") && condition.hasOwnProperty("bedrooms")  && condition.hasOwnProperty("Inhibition") && !condition.hasOwnProperty("budgetPrice")): {

            subCondition[dbId]=requestId;
            andCondition.push(subCondition,Sequelize.literal("`hp_property`.`property_completion_date` between now() and DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL "+condition.possession+" MONTH)"),Sequelize.literal("`hp_unit_details`.`hp_unit_type_id` IN (" + condition.bedrooms + ")"),Sequelize.literal("`hp_unit_details`.`hp_unit_type_id` IN (" + condition.bedrooms + ")"),Sequelize.literal("`hp_property`.`hp_property_inhibition_status_id` IN (" + condition.Inhibition + ")"))
            obj['$and']=andCondition;
            return obj;
        }
            break;



        default:{
            obj[dbId] =requestId
            return  obj;
        }




    }

}
```

Comment: please add an example of an object to test against and the relevan constraints to test, and an example of what should happen after the test.

Comment: everthing is working fine .but iam writing almost 100 switch cases for that give me some solution.u can observe  that image . u can get some idea

Comment: sorry, but without any sense of your data structure it is almost impossible to help you. anyway, ha small hint, you could replace `condition.hasOwnProperty("possession")` with `"possession" in condition`.

Comment: i have to handle only single object.but with different keys checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could just easily treat each condition separately

something like

```
var andCondition = [];
subCondition[dbId]=requestId;
andCondition.push(subCondition)
if(condition.hasOwnProperty("Inhibition")) {
    andCondition.push(Sequelize.literal("`hp_property`.`hp_property_    inhibition_status_id` IN (" + condition.Inhibition + ")"));
};
if(condition.hasOwnProperty("bedrooms")) {           
    andCondition.push(Sequelize.literal("`hp_unit_details`.`hp_unit_    type_id` IN (" + condition.bedrooms + ")");
}
if(condition.hasOwnProperty("budgetPrice")) {
    var budgetPrice = condition.budgetPrice.split(",");
    var minRange = budgetPrice[0];
    var maxRange = budgetPrice[1];       
    andCondition.push(Sequelize.literal("`hp_unit_details.hp_unit_prices`.`price_    per_sqft` * `hp_unit_details`.`property_size`  BETWEEN " + minRange + " AND " + maxRange));
}
if(condition.hasOwnProperty("possession")): {
    andCondition.push(Sequelize.literal("`hp_property`.`property_completion_date`     between now() and DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL "+condition.possession+" MONTH)"));
}
obj['$and']=andCondition;

return obj;
```

Comment: you are my hero man .i am missing small logic . thanq a lot please give some links to improve this type of logics and links.but thanq a lot man